# Bad results using Hopfield network for recognize image pattern

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wrote a code in matlab for image pattern recognition with Hopfield Network.
I have no error in my code.As I use letter pattern, good results are obtained. but when I use number pattern,the results are divergent. For this purpose, I use two different patterns for six numbers.
If it is possible please guide me.

```
matlab
% Retrieval phase

for input = 1:6 

    figure(input+1);
    set(gcf,'Name','Testing Covergence from 2nd input to 1st input')
    subplot(4,5,2)
    Imageplot1(P(:,input),Dimension,Dimension);
    xlabel('1st pat')
    subplot(4,5,4)
    Imageplot1(P2(:,input),Dimension,Dimension)
    xlabel('2nd pat')

    update = 400 ; % iritation to show

    Input = P2(:,input);
    plot='on';

    %% my check 
    Out = zeros(Dime,1) ;
    Counter = 1 ;

    for j = 1:Dime
        Out(j) = sign(W(j,:)*Input);        %Convergence Condition

        if Out(j)~= Input(j)
            Input(j) = Out (j) ;
            Iteration(:,Counter) = Input ;
            Counter = Counter + 1 ;
        end
    end

    It_n = ceil ( Counter / update ) ;
    figure (input + 1)

    for n = 1 : It_n
        if (n * update) < (Counter - 1)
        subplot(4,5,5+n)
        Imageplot1(Iteration(:,n * update),Dimension,Dimension);
        pause(0.3);
        end
    end

        subplot(4,5,18)
        Imageplot1(Iteration(:,end),Dimension,Dimension);
        xlabel('final Iteration')
        clear Iteration

end
```